# How to keep cmd from exiting using Java 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec' command

Tags: java, windows, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to compile and execute a .java file, using a java program.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start javac myProg.java");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java myProg");
```

The file compiles and i think it runs as well but then it exits. I need to keep the cmd window open.

I tried using `\k` instead of `\c` and using `pause`. They don't seem to work. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Have you tried this? `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k javac myProg.java"); Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java myProg");`

Comment: :D :D Thank you so much @PramodKarandikar. Worked like a dream :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in your code and it will work. You need to add option `/k` as shown below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k javac myProg.java"); 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java myProg");
```